# iOS comments in Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin iOS and I have a `Localizable.strings` file where I keep all my strings. It's becoming very cluttered now and was wondering if there was a way to add comments in this file to better organize it?

Comment: // This is how you add comments in localizable.strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual convention for adding comments to the `.strings` file is as follows:

```
/* Comment */
"key" = "localized-value";
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/#.strings_file_format

Answer (score -1):

The reason I couldn't add comments was because my `.strings` file was in JSON format. I changed it to the format BytesGuy showed and it works now.

Comment: Glad that helped! Can you mark my response as the answer?

Comment: Edit your response to mention that I can't have comments while using JSON format, and I'll mark it as the correct answer (so it will help others with the same question too)

Comment: The `.strings` files used in iOS projects are always in key-value notation as shown in my answer. I have not seen them in other formats, such as JSON, before - out of interest do you have an example of this working? Irrespective of this, JSON does not have any facility for comments regardless of platform etc.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin, and someone in my team started the localization file using JSON format, and it works for us: `{ "key": "value" }`